# How to get all rows from a database where foreign key is equal to the result of a query?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I have a table of "Articles" that has a foreign key of "category_id".

Articles

```
| id | title | pub_date | category_id |
-----------------------------------
|  0 | abc   | 23423443 |    1        |
|  1 | def   | 23423423 |    2        |
|  2 | ghi   | 24234234 |    1        |
|  3 | jkl   | 23423424 |    3        |
|  4 | mop   | 23432435 |    2        |
```

Categories

```
| id | title   |
----------------
|  1 | News    |
|  2 | Feature |
|  3 | Review  |
```

I have the title of a category.

I would like to, in one query, ascertain the id of said category and use it to return articles where the category_id = id and publish date is less than the current date time.

Is this possible?

I am using Postgres but I am looking at this from an academic standpoint so answers in any SQL dialect would be fine as I am happy to do the translation myself for the education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just a simple join
try

```
SELECT A.id,A.title,A.pub_date,A.category_id,
       C.title
FROM Articles A
INNER JOIN Categories C
ON A.category_id = C.id
WHERE pub_date < NOW()
  AND C.title = "your title"
```

Comment: I added the extra WHERE clause for the specific Category title, but this helped me get to the answer I needed thank you.

Comment: there i updated my query to show this fact that you're looking for a specific category title. i don't think i heard you mention this in your question. but yeah

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
    from Articles
  where pub_date <= now() and 
        category_id = (select id from Categories where title="TITLE")
```

Comment: This helped a lot, I ended up going the JOIN route rather than sub query but thanks for your answer.

Comment: ok. i think @BobSalmon answer is better among join variants because the where clause `title = CATEGORY TITLE` whould reduce the temp table and so the time of execution

Comment: Whether a sub-query (as in this answer) or join is better, the answer is: it depends (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).  This answer is a bit old, but I think still relevant.  It's worth knowing how to do both, so you can use whichever works best in your situation (which may vary).

Comment: @BobSalmoni am not comparing your and my answers. I wrote about two answers with join :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?  I don't know if this is PostgresSQL or not.

```
select A.id, A.title, A.pub_date, C.id, C.title
from Articles A join Categories C on A.category_id=C.id
where C.title = MY_CATEGORY_TITLE and
a.pub_date < CURRENT_DATE_TIME
```

I'm ignoring the need for indexes, orders etc.

Comment: This worked perfectly, Tin Tran just got there first. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  If you haven't already, it's probably worth reading up on the different kinds of join (inner, outer, left and right).  I was sloppy and didn't specify (assuming it would default to inner).  Tin Tran has also used inner - I think that's what you need here - but it's useful to know about the other kinds too.

Comment: I have looked into them a little bit before now but I can see now that I have a lot to learn. Just thinking my way through the problem with all the possible join variants is in itself somewhat of a brain game. Might be worth me cloning my DB and having a play with some of them. Thanks again.